# simultaneous connections in XP/Vista/Win7

Tags: windows, iis, printing

IIS 7 on Vista does not limit the number of allowed connections as IIS on XP did but limits concurrent requests to 10 (Windows Vista Ultimate, Business, and Enterprise Editions) or 3 (Vista Home Premium). Additional requests are queued which hampers performance but they are not rejected as with XP.

This is what I got from wiki, but I wonder how does it work in Win7?

Answer (score 1):

No limit in Win 7 at all. Sensibly.

[One assumes no retrograde step from this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969710)

Edit:

Of course, the limit in XP is applied before any IIS limitations. With Win 7 and later versions, the only bottleneck is IIS and not the half-open tcp limit.

Comment: Windows 7 (IIS v7.5)2        
Starter:     No IIS;
Home Basic:     No IIS;
Home Premium:     simultaneous request execution limit of 3;
Business:     simultaneous request execution limit of 10;
Enterprise:     simultaneous request execution limit of 10;
Ultimate:     simultaneous request execution limit of 10;

Got this from a technical site just now.
Any thoughts of no limit VS limit of 10?